# Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate) while creating push notification P EM file

Tags: ios, ssl, terminal, push-notification, certificate

I am creating  PEM file for Production APNS , and i have done this several time before .

But i am facing an error on terminal while testing my PEm file from below command :

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 
    -cert myCert.pem -key myKey.pem
```

It gives me :

> Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)

as response.

I have tried so many times but did not identify the problem .

May be it is because of my distribution certificates created on diffrent Mac .
But i am not sure .
Any help suggestion will be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a *CA certificate* as `CAfile` commandline argument to `s_client`. The trusted root certificate for the push servers is the Entrust CA (2048) root certificate which you can download from [Entrust's site](https://www.entrust.com/root-certificates/entrust_2048_ca.cer).

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 
    -cert myCert.pem -key myKey.pem -CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer
```

For more information and other possible reasons, please, check Apple developer guide [Troubleshooting Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The developer link asks to include -CAfile server-ca-cert.pem, which does'nt work either.
All other options of indicating the CAfile gave me errors like 'unable to load certificate'.

The below actually worked for me after trying other options.

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 
-cert myCert.pem -key myKey.pem -CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer
```

This solution gives 'Verify return code: 0 (ok)'.

On an additional note: You can also specify the .key file as the -key value & it will work too i.e. something like, ref [here](http://zewaren.net/site/node/131)

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert myCert.pem -key myprivatekey.key -CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer
```